# while loop with two specific conditions

Tags: python

I've got a code something like:

```
list1 = input()

while list1 != "y" or list1 != "n":
  print()
  print("INVALID INPUT")
  print()
  list1 = input()
```

and whenever I run it I get stuck in the loop regardless of the input.

I'd like the loop to end if I enter in either "y" or "n".

Comment: Change the or to an and

Comment: A better way to check for valid answers is either `list1 not in "yn"` or `list1 not in ("y","n")`. The latter expression allows comparing to multicharacter strings.

Comment: This kind of problem can be debugged by shortening your code (e.g. the condition) until nothing can possibly go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what list1 is, it cannot be both "y" and "n", so it is always not one of them. I think you mean "and" not "or."

Answer (score 0):

a variable can't have 2 values, so having `while list1 != "y" or list1 != "n"` is an endless loop cause `list1` will certainly be different than at least one of them.

What you want is `while list1 != "y" **and** list1 != "n"`. That way, for any value that is not `y` nor `n` the loop will continue.